# Is there anytthing different with the size() and length() of std::string

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::string length() and size() member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905479/stdstring-length-and-size-member-functions)

In my opinion size() and length() both mean the length of characters stored in the string.Is there anyting different with them.

Answer (score 2):

No. They are identical. See C++11, 21.4.4/3:

> `size_type length() const noexcept;`
>
> Returns: `size()`.