# How to get length of a string using strlen function

Tags: c++, string

I have following code that gets and prints a string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << str;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But how to count the number of characters in this string using `strlen()` function?

Comment: How about `str.size()`?

Comment: `main` must return `int`.

Comment: Why `strlen` exactly?

Comment: So we cant count character in a string using strlen() function?

Comment: `size()` or `length()` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size

Comment: @AkashSharma, You could, but why would you? It won't count past the first 0 character, either, if that's a possibility for your string to store.

Comment: Why two function `size()` and `length()` are given ? Any specific reason? Because Both are doing same work.

Comment: @AkashSharma: A serious question: Where did you get the idea that `void main()` is correct? The correct definition is `int main()` in C++, `int main(void)` in C.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes My mistake, But I have seen many programs in C they are using void main() instead int main(void)

Comment: @AkashSharma: Yes, I've seen far too many such programs myself, and too many poorly written books that recommend it. Did you read that in a book somewhere?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes :) In my college book

Comment: Title? Author? It was apparently written by someone who doesn't know the language very well, and it may contain more serious mistakes. I'd like to warn people away from it.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

For C++ strings, there's no reason to use `strlen`. Just use `string::length`:

```
std::cout << str.length() << std::endl;
```

You should *strongly* prefer this to `strlen(str.c_str())` for the following reasons:

1. ***Clarity***: The `length()` (or `size()`) member functions unambiguously give back the length of the string. While it's possible to figure out what `strlen(str.c_str())` does, it forces the reader to pause for a bit.
2. ***Efficiency***: `length()` and `size()` run in time O(1), while `strlen(str.c_str())` will take Θ(n) time to find the end of the string.
3. ***Style***: It's good to prefer the C++ versions of functions to the C versions unless there's a specific reason to do so otherwise. This is why, for example, it's usually considered better to use `std::sort` over `qsort` or `std::lower_bound` over `bsearch`, unless some other factors come into play that would affect performance.

The only reason I could think of where `strlen` would be useful is if you had a C++-style string that had embedded null characters and you wanted to determine how many characters appeared before the first of them. (That's one way in which `strlen` differs from `string::length`; the former stops at a null terminator, and the latter counts all the characters in the string). But if that's the case, just use `string::find`:

```
size_t index = str.find(0);
if (index == str::npos) index = str.length();
std::cout << index << std::endl;
```

Comment: Your code is correct , but i have read that all functions of c are imported in C++ and we can use strlen in C , how to use in C++

Comment: @AkashSharma- You *can* use `strlen` on a C++ string by writing `strlen(str.c_str())`, but this would be extremely poor style. Although C++ absorbs C's standard library, the C++ standard libraries often include more C++-friendly versions of those functions, and there's no reason to use `strlen` when you could just be using `string::length`.

Comment: If i want to use `strlen()` then Why can't I use `strlen(str);`

Comment: @AkashSharma- `strlen` accepts `const char*`, and `std::string` isn't a `const char*`. That said - it is really not a good idea to use `strlen` here!

Comment: Ok, But another issue why there are two functions `size()` and `length()` as i can see both doing same work?

Comment: @AkashSharma- I believe it's historical. The STL contains use `size()`, and I think historically `string` used `length()`. It's probably for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Correct. There's running C++ code going back 20+ years, and we strive not to break reasonable code. That's also why `strlen` is still valid: we may have better alternatives, but old code doesn't magically change to use those.

Comment: There's actually a difference I stumbled across lately: If you do `str[4]` where `str.length() == 100`, then afterwards `strlen(str.c_str()) == 4` whereas still `str.length() == 100`.
(Old answer, but better late than never:)

Comment: @Xlea You probably mean `str[4] = '\0'`?

Comment: @zenith Right, I do.

Answer (score 7):

Function [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) shows the number of character before `\0` and using it for `std::string` may report wrong length.

```
strlen(str.c_str()); // It may return wrong length.
```

In C++, a string can contain `\0` within the characters but C-style-zero-terminated strings can not but at the end. If the `std::string` has a `\0` before the last character then `strlen` reports a length less than the actual length.

Try to use [`.length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) or [`.size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), I prefer second one since another standard containers have it.

```
str.size()
```

Comment: `.size` was correct, too. I actually use it instead of `length`.

Comment: Why two functions size() and length() are given in C++ ? Any specific reason? Because Both are doing same work.

Comment: @AkashSharma You can check it here: [size and length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905479/stdstring-length-and-size-member-functions)

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::string::size` or `std::string::length` (both are the same).

As you insist to use `strlen`, you can:

```
int size = strlen( str.c_str() );
```

note the usage of `std::string::c_str`, which returns `const char*`.

**BUT** `strlen` counts untill it hit `\0` char and `std::string` can store such chars. In other words, `strlen` could sometimes lie for the size.

Comment: [`c_str()`documentation from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str): Returns a pointer to a **null-terminated character array** with data equivalent to those stored in the string.

Comment: @Johan: Not necessarily. A `std::string` can contain embedded null characters. If you have a `std::string` `foo` with the value `"foo\0bar"`, it's `.length()` is 7, but `strlen(foo.c_str())` will return 3.

Comment: My mistake, I read your message the other way (that there was no '\0' at the end).

Comment: Sorry I removed my previous comment that was becaming meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really want to use strlen(), then

```
cout << strlen(str.c_str()) << endl;
```

else the use of .length() is more in keeping with C++.

Answer (score 0):

Manually:

```
int strlen(string s)
{
    int len = 0;

    while (s[len])
        len++;

    return len;
}
```

Comment: Are you serious or being sarcastic? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    char str[80];

    int i;

    cout<<"\n enter string:";

    cin.getline(str,80);

    int n=strlen(str);

    cout<<"\n lenght is:"<<n;

    getch();

    return 0;

}
```

This is the program if you want to use strlen .
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Simply use

> int len=str.length();