# Count letters in String without using strlen()

Tags: c++, string

I created a program that the user enters a string. But i need to count how many letters are in the string. The problem is im not allowed to use the `strlen()`function. So i found some methods but they use pointers but im not allowed to use that yet as we havent learned it. Whats the best way to do this in a simple method? I also tried chars but i dont have luck with that either.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string long;
string short;


int main()
{

        cout << "Enter long string";
        cin >> long;


        cout << "Enter short string";
        cin >> short;



    return 0;
}
```

I need to get the length of long and short and print it.

I am trying to use it without doing strlen as asked in some previous questions.

Comment: `cout <<long.size()`, but you need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: `long` and `short` are keywords that you can't (portably) use as variable names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ String Length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905355/c-string-length)

Comment: No im doing it without strlen @FabioTurati

Comment: @sonicboom Sorry, I had misunderstood your question, I thought you had said that `strlen()` isn't allowed because it works with C-style strings, and you are using `std::string`. The answer I've linked explains that you can use `string::size()` or `string::length()` in this case. But now I understand you are not allowed to use those functions either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
//random string given

int length = 1;
while(some_string[length - 1] != '\0')
  length++;
```

Or if you don't want to count the `\0` character:

```
int length = 0;
while(some_string[length] != '\0')
  length++;
```

Comment: Im just getting 3 for the value of length after running this.. Its not accurate @naltipar

Comment: If i enter 2, i get 3.

Comment: I fixed it by subtracting 1

Comment: Read the updated version, I thought you wanted to include the `\0` character.

Comment: @downvoter it's generally a good idea to explain why you downvote the answer.

Comment: What is \0 ?   What does it stand for.

Comment: It is an extra character always stored in the end of the string, to denote its end. You might be setting a string to be 2 characters long, but `\0` is placed in the end, making it 3 character long.

Comment: The one where i dont want to count \0 isnt working and the one above wont compile

Comment: Normally, you never count the '\0' character, so the second solution should be preferred. Also in the first code the \0 seems to miss some single quotes to me. Oh, and the code some_string[lengt - 1] is dangerous and leads to an error in the second code.

Comment: Your 2nd version accesses `some_string[-1]`. That can't be good. The first one doesn't get the length right. So, both are wrong. You're lucky to get up-votes.

Comment: Yeah, I did some mistakes while editing the post, thanks for those comments

Comment: It is just amazing, how one of the simplest coding peaces can be difficult  to implement correctly ... It is a good example, why to use solid libraries.

Comment: @Juergen It is actually trivial to implement correctly. What is hard is to match the efficiency of `strlen`.

Comment: Sh*t happens at night.

Answer (score 1):

You can count from the beginning and see until you reach the end character `\0`.

```
std::string foo = "hello";

int length = 0;
while (foo[++length] != '\0');

std::cout << length;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use standard cpp string object I think the best way to get length of your string is to use method:

```
long.size();
```

It gives you number of characters in string without end string character '\0'. To use it you must include string library :

```
#include <string>
```

If you decide to use char table you can try method from cin:

```
char long_[20];
cout << "Enter long string\n";
int l = cin.getline(long_,20).gcount(); 
cout << l << endl;
```

[gcount()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/?kw=gcount)