# How to find the lenght of the word in C++?

Tags: c++, string, cpu-word

We have some word, that we should identify the length of. How can I do that?
Example INPUT: "hello" - without quotes;
Example OUTPUT: 5

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/

Comment: The answer in this case is simply to search, which doesn't make for a good question on SO.

Comment: Things like this should be covered in any [decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Or you could do a quick search on the internet "C++ get length of string".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the number of characters in a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905355/how-to-get-the-number-of-characters-in-a-stdstring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If input is contained in a std::string you can find the length as stated by Ravi.
If it's a C string you find the length with

```
int len = strlen(INPUT);
```

In C/C++ upper case is normally used for constants so it's better to name the string *input*, not *INPUT*.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str;
cin>>str;
//use this
cout<<str.length();
//or use this
cout<<str.size();
```

both of them will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is one function to find length in C++.
You can try by using:

```
input.length()
```

Also remember, you need to include:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Refer this document :
https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_strings_length.asp

Comment: You don't need to inlcude iostream to use `std::string`. And you shouldn't use `using namespace std;`, it's [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input.length() or input.size()`.

Or you can use this simple loop.

```
 for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) 
        ; 
    cout << i << endl;
```

Comment: Don't recommend newbies to roll their own version of standard functions. It it totally unnecessary.

Comment: That loop does what `std::strlen` does, but `std::string` is allowed to contain additional null-characters, so it's different from `std::string::length`.